# Linksys E2000 loses connection about every 4 to 8 hours

Tags: wireless-networking, router, connection, chromecast

**TL;DR:** Linksys E2000 (firmware 1.0.06; newest) drops Wi-Fi after 4-8 hours (SSID still broadcast but no connections possible) and my Chromecast won’t connect.

**More details:** The Linksys E2000 is in my room right above my TV. The wired connection from it to my computer works like a charm but the Wi-Fi seems mostly broken.

I have to reboot the router every about every 4 to 8 hours to make Wi-Fi work again, and my Chromecast won’t connect to it regardless. It either can't connect at all or connects but then has no internet access.

The setup is; ISP modem/router that handles TV and everything has 3 routers hooked into it, the ISP modem/router handles DHCP and the routers are all set up correctly, two work fine and this one just has Wi-Fi problems.

Are there any common settings issues that could cause this? I looked at some guides on the Linksys E3000 (I also have a Linksys E3000 and a Linksys EA4500) but the settings that seemed to matter are set correctly in my Linksys E2000.

Comment: Most routers have the wireless channel set to Auto, set it to a fixed channel. Set it to channel 1,6 or 11, you may have to try all 3 before you find a stable wireless channel.

Comment: I have tried my laptop, my HTC One X, Nexus 6, HTC One, an HTC One S and a Sony Xperia Z3 plus a few different other laptops. All have the same problem

Will try setting the channel